# Angular google maps api interaction issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the angular google maps api to display the people as points on the map. I have 2 linked pages which both use the same code for the map interaction. The interaction works on page 1 but it doesn't on the 2nd page. I'm not sure how to fix this as well due to the code being exactly the same on both pages.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_territory" style="width:50%;"
                ng-options="territory as territory.name for territory in main_map | filter: {area_id:selected_area.area_id}" id="" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></select>
        </div>
        <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:80%">
            <ui-gmap-google-map id="my-map" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" bounds="map.bounds">
                <ui-gmap-markers models="mapping" coords="'location'" idKey="'id'" click="select_kol"
                                 options="kol_marker_options">
                    <ui-gmap-windows show="show" options="infoWindowOptions">
                        <div ng-non-bindable>
```

This is my code so far.

Also on a separate note I need to add a search bar to dynamically search for the names of the people displayed on the table. Any help to make the same would be appreciated as well.

The table input values are read from a JSON file using js and filtered using the selected territory.